# UIBarButtonItem subclass doesn't call action when keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I'm having a bit of a pickle.
I've subclassed a UIBarButtonItem so I can set it's "state". This is just so I can easily change the image and delegate method that is called depending on it's state.

Weird thing is happening now that when I tap this button when the keyboard is being shown, it's action is not getting called. Once I remove the keyboard by doing `[self.view endEditing:YES];` it works again.

Any ideas?

The .m file of the subclass:

```
#import "ActionBarButton.h"

@implementation ActionBarButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    [self setAction:@selector(buttonTapped)];
}

- (void)setState:(ActionBarButtonState)state
{
    _state = state;

    switch (state) {
        case ActionBarButtonStateEdit:
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TraderOverview_Edit"];
            break;
        case ActionBarButtonStateNone:
            self.image = nil;
            break;
        case ActionBarButtonStateSave:
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Save_20x20"];
            break;
        case ActionBarButtonStateCategories:
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackToCategories_20x20"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)buttonTapped
{
    switch (_state) {
        case ActionBarButtonStateEdit:
            [self.delegate actionButtonTappedEdit];
            break;
        case ActionBarButtonStateNone:
            // do nothing
            break;
        case ActionBarButtonStateSave:
            [self.delegate actionButtonTappedSave];
            break;
        case ActionBarButtonStateCategories:
            [self.delegate actionButtonTappedCategories];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Does the `buttonTapped` method get called when the keyboard is not displayed? I found I had to add `[self setTarget:self];` to the `setup` method to get the delegate method called at all.

Comment: @dkw5877 Holy shtfks, that little call made it work... To answer your question, yes it worked perfectly when the keyboard was not showing.